# How to list out pdf files of iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, pdf

I want to upload pdf file in my application.

My question is **how i will get pdf list? Like `UIImagepicker` is there any controller for document picker**.

Please help me.

Comment: You can try the quick Look frame work.

Comment: from where you want to pick pdf file? from your application's bundle or documents directory ? or from any other app ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [UIDocumentMenuViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentMenuViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIDocumentMenuViewController).

You can refer [DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) of apple.

You can do something like,

```
  UIDocumentMenuViewController *myDocumentMenu = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:docArr inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
myDocumentMenu.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController: myDocumentMenu animated:YES completion: ^{
    NSLog(@"presented sucessfullly");
}];
```

You can also refer [Appcoda's tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-previewing-and-opening-documents--mobile-15130).